# C# ActiveDirectory LDAP Group Querying

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I have an ASP.Net web application that's using Forms Authentication with some custom code to link it to ActiveDirectory (very similar to how [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302397.aspx) works).

However, whenever I query the domain controller for the users groups it only returns the groups that they're explicitly in and not subgroups (id est, there's a specific Security Group that the user belongs to, say group A, that is a member of the group I want, say group B, the user is explicitly in group A, but only implicitly in group B because group A is a member of group B).

I've read the tokenGroups querying could help me out here but currently I don't have a way to parse that data.

However what would be most preferable is if I could pass certain groups via an LDAP query and have the Domain controller just give me a boolean (true/false) if that user is within that group or not.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the "usual" `user.Properties["memberOf"]` only returns direct memberships.

If you're using .NET 3.5 however, you can use the more modern "principal-based" methods:

```
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using(Principal p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "yourUserName"))
    {
        var groups = p.GetGroups();

        using (groups)
        {
            foreach (Principal group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group.SamAccountName + "-" + group.DisplayName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method (add a reference to the "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" assembly to your project) should work and deliver the user's primary group and its nested group memberships as well.

If you're on .NET 2.0/3.0 and can't move up, using the approach by reading the "tokenGroups" attribute is the best approach - see the details about how to do all of this in Ryan Dunn's excellent blog post, [Enumerating Token Groups (tokenGroups) in .NET](http://dunnry.com/blog/EnumeratingTokenGroupsTokenGroupsInNET.aspx).

Marc

Comment: The tokenGroups method worked flawlessly.  Unfortunately we're not on 3.5 so I can't try the new method but that link you gave for the tokenGroups setup worked great.  Thanks.