# C# Active Directory Group Querying

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322791/c-sharp-activedirectory-ldap-group-querying).

I am getting the following compile time error:

The name 'p' does not exist in the current context

Here is my code...can someone help?  Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

 public static List<string> GetGroups()
 {
     using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
     {
         using (p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "yourUserName")) 
         {
            var groups = p.GetGroups();
            using (groups)
            {
                foreach (Principal group in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(group.SamAccountName + "-" + group.DisplayName); 
                } 
            }
        }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, that code you use was created by me in response to another question - and I had this error in there. Sorry for that - it's been fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

You never declare `p`.  You need to change the code to this:

```
// Add a "var" below
using (var p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "yourUserName"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a type for your variable `p`:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (Principal p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "yourUserName")) 
{
    var groups = p.GetGroups();

    foreach (Principal group in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.SamAccountName + "-" + group.DisplayName); 
    } 
}
```

PS: Sorry, that code you use was created by me in response to another question - and I had this error in there. Sorry for that - it's been fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Hey, it's called "padding the stats"! :)

Answer (score 1):

You never declare `p`.

Try this:

```
using (var p = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "yourUserName"))
```